# Show that $\Vert x \Vert=\sqrt{\Vert x \Vert_1^2+\Vert x \Vert_2^2} $ is a norm

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $ \Vert . \Vert_1 $ and $\Vert . \Vert _2 $ be two norms on a vector space $V$. Prove that $\Vert x \Vert=\sqrt{\Vert x \Vert_1^2+\Vert x \Vert_2^2} $ for $x \in V$ is also a norm.

I'm getting stuck on trying to show the triangle inequality for this.

$$\begin{align} \Vert x+y \Vert&=\sqrt{\Vert x+y \Vert_1^2+\Vert x+y \Vert_2^2} \\ 
&\le \sqrt{\Vert x \Vert_1^2+\Vert x \Vert_2^2 + \Vert y \Vert_1^2+\Vert y \Vert_2^2+2\Vert x \Vert_1\Vert y \Vert_1 +2\Vert x \Vert_2\Vert y \Vert_2} \end{align}$$

But I get stuck here.

Also from minkowski's inequality we see that

$$\begin{align} \Vert x+y \Vert=\sqrt{\Vert x+y \Vert_1^2+\Vert x+y \Vert_2^2} &\le \Vert x+y \Vert_1 + \Vert x+y \Vert_2 \\
&\le \Vert x \Vert_1 +\Vert x \Vert_2 + \Vert y \Vert_1 + \Vert y \Vert_2 \end{align}$$
But then I'm stuck on how to move forward.

Any hints on how to show the triangle inequality for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\sqrt{(a+a')^2+(b+b')^2}\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{{a'}^2+{b'}^2}$

$\sqrt{\|x+y\|^2_1+\|x+y\|_2}$

$\leq \sqrt{(\|x\|_1+\|y\|_1)^2+(\|x\|_2+\|y\|_2)^2}\leq \sqrt{\|x\|_1^2+\|x\|_2^2}+\sqrt{\|y\|_1^2+\|y\|_2^2}$.

Comment: I feel dumb lol, I was staring at minkowskis inequality thinking that I had to use it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By C-S we obtain:
$$\|x\|+\|y\|=\sqrt{\|x\|_1^2+\|x\|_2^2}+\sqrt{\|y\|_1^2+\|y\|_2^2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\|x\|_1^2+\|x\|_2^2+\|y\|_1^2+\|y\|_2^2+2\sqrt{\left(\|x\|_1^2+\|x\|_2^2\right)\left(\|y\|_1^2+\|y\|_2^2\right)}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\|x\|_1^2+\|x\|_2^2+\|y\|_1^2+\|y\|_2^2+2\|x\|_1\|y\|_1+2\|x\|_2\|y\|_2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\|x+y\|_1^2+\|x+y\|_2^2}=\|x+y\|.$$
Done!